# Derivative of Marginal df equal to marginal pdf?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, marginal-distribution

I am curious as to when the derivative of a marginal df is equal to the marginal pdf for a (continuous) random variable.

As a simple example, let Z = (X,Y)  be a continuous random vector and F be the df of Z. Assuming the processes of integrating and differentiation can be exchanged, then it would seem like the marginal pdf for X should be equal to the derivative of the marginal df for X. Is this correct and if so, when can we say this is possible (I believe that for 1 variable, F uniformly continuous generally implies derivatives and integrals can be exchanged with limiting processes).

Comment: Try defining what the marginal pdf *is*. What does it tell you?

Comment: Not sure... f(x) := mpdf of x = integral of f(x,y) over the support of one var (say Y). F(x) := marginal pdf of X = limit as y goes to infinity of the integral of f on from X=-inf to x and Y from -inf to y. So this goes back to my question of when I can sneak the derivative operator past the limit (on F)

Comment: I didn't ask you to derive a formula for it -- what object is it you tried to derive the formula for? I don't mean its name, either. Consider - what is the pdf of a random variable? What does it tell you?

Comment: I guess I'm just not seeing your point. I know pdf is the function you integrate to get the probability that a random vector in R^2 (say in this example) lies in some subset. I don't know what it really tells me beyond the definition.

Comment: OKay ... we could even manage with that. If the pdf is merely "the object you integrate to get the probability the random variable lies in some subset" then what's the probability that a vector-random variable $X$ is $\leq x$? (where $x$ is also vector-valued)

Comment: Really, the thing I am trying to get you to think about is what is the *random variable* this df and pdf are the df and pdf *of*? You've learned formulas for working them out in particular situations but don't seem to see what the objects themselves are (the random variables) that you're computing dfs and pdfs for. What is it that's 'lying in some subset', as you said before?

Comment: Try it this way. One could plausibly argue that in any real application there is no such thing as a *single* random variable: in any system there are many kinds of measurements that could be recorded, so that any single random variable $X$ could always be thought of as one component within a host of other variables that we simply ignore. Whence "the" distribution of $X$ is really always a marginal distribution of $X$ with respect to all those other forgotten variables. From this point of view, *all* distributions are marginal distributions--and your question disappears entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> Try it this way. One could plausibly argue that in any real application there is no such thing as a *single* random variable: in any system there are many kinds of measurements that could be recorded, so that any single random variable $X$ could always be thought of as one component within a host of other variables that we simply ignore. Whence "the" distribution of $X$ is really always a marginal distribution of $X$ with respect to all those other forgotten variables. From this point of view, *all* distributions are marginal distributions--and your question disappears entirely.   –
> whuber